# External SWF variable updates global variable in Main timeline

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, actionscript-2, global-variables

I have been searching all over and have yet to find an actual working solution for this

I have 2 movie clips, one being loaded into a container MC via "loadMovie();"

In the main movie there is a variable with no value, in the external movie there are 5 frames, each with a value to update the variable in the main movie.

IE: if on frame 1, global value = 1  /  if on frame 2, global value = 2 / etc etc

I'm familiar with passing variables INTO an external swf, but am stumped on how to do it the reverse way.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a variable (for example 'myVariable') on the main timeline with _root.myVariable

Better still, you can use a relative reference such as this._parent.myVariable (or this._parent._parent.myVariable if you are two clips deep...)

There's more details [here](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/tricks/root_parent_this.htm), also [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/as_bestpractices_04.html).

Comment: Richard, thanks for the timely response!
However, still unsuccessful...

Just for testing, in the EXTERNAL MC i've assigned two buttons, each change the value of the variable.  but, when i try to trace the variable on the MAIN MC i keep getting "undefined" in the output...

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're using to set and trace the variables?